# How to remove a table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector

Just want to know how to select a table row by id

eg the table row has the id of "50"

...

How can I select this (as I wish to use the hide() function on a click)

Comment: Almost got it..
This is my code

$('.remove').click(function () {
        var row = '';
        row = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(row);   
        $('tr#'.row).hide();              
    });

Comment: Got it  - thanks guys
    $('.remove').click(function () {
        var row = '';
        row = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(row);   
        $('tr#'+row).hide();              
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('tr#50')
```

be careful with number-only ids though

Answer (score 2):

```
$('tr#50').click(function(ev) { $(this).hide(); });
```

`$('tr#50')` selects the row. `.click(function(){...})` runs the function when you click on the row. `$(this)` is a way of selecting the original element that you set the click handler on (in this case, that selected by "tr#50"). And `.hide()`, obviously, hides that element.

*EDIT: As other answerers point out, it's not good practice to start an id with a number, and even worse practice to make your id only a number. You should rename it to something like `row-50`.*

Answer (score 1):

write this on Click event

```
 $('tr#50').hide()
```

But i would suggest you that don't start your id with Number as  it's not a good practice ...

Answer (score 0):

To select an element with an id just use the following selector:

```
$("tr#id").hide();
```

So for your problem with the id 50 it would be:

```
$("tr#50").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an ID of the table and simply wants to select the 50th row, you can select it with:

```
$('table tr').eq(49);
```

or

```
$('table tr:eq(49)');
```

Note that eq() starts on 0, and not 1. There for the eq() in this case is (50 - 1)

Comment: When we are having id, then why you are going for `eq`..it will be much slower

Comment: I felt the question to be too simple to mean the id="" attribute, and therefor drew the conlusion the questioner may have meant this instead. I've also read that id="" shouldn't start with a number.